# Add UITableView Cell TextField values to Array? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with cells that contain 3 `textField`s.

Each cell is identical and collects, from the user, the same input data: "event", "date", and "review" using the 3 `textField`s in each cell.

After the user is done choosing how many entries they would like to make and the cell replicates these form fields, I would like to take the values of each cell and put them into arrays named:
`var events = []` `var dates = []` and `var reviews = []`. Or alternatively, into an array of arrays with event, date, and review as one array.

How would I be able to get the user's input in each of these table cells, extract the data, and store them into these arrays?

I have scoured Google without success... (Gulp) Help!

**UPDATE**

Here is some more info to help you know what I mean. The user says that they want to make 3 entries into their journal. The UITableView then populates with 3 cells that are identical:

**UITABLE CELL 1**

- **EVENT** [ blank text field ]
- **DATE** [ blank text field ]
- **REVIEW** [ blank text view ]

**UITABLE CELL 2**

- **EVENT** [ blank text field ]
- **DATE** [ blank text field ]
- **REVIEW** [ blank text view ]

**UITABLE CELL 3**

- **EVENT** [ blank text field ]
- **DATE** [ blank text field ]
- **REVIEW** [ blank text view ]

Afterwards, this data is turned into multidimensional JSON data and parsed by PHP (that part is already done and works with stub data). My goal is for the data in the end to look like this in Swift:

```
var  userData  = [
[
    "event": "user event 1",
    "date": "user date 1",
    "review": "user review 1"
],
[
    "event": "user event 2",
    "date": "user date 2",
    "review": "user review 2"
],
[
    "event": "user event 3",
    "date": "user date 3",
    "review": "user review 3"
] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get all visible cells indexpath using this:

   ```
   NSArray *paths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
   ```
2. Then get all the cells in some array:

   NSMutableSet *visibleCells = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

   ```
   for (NSIndexPath *path in paths) {
       [visibleCells addObject:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path]];
   }
   ```
3. Then you can get textfield values from each cell:

   for (UITableViewCell *thisCell in visibleCells) {
           //printing textfield
           NSLog(@"%@\n", thisCell.textField.text);
       }

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Would you happen to know the Swift version of doing this? As much as I wish I was more verbose in Obj-C, I'm only a Swift guy :)

Answer (score 0):

The strategy you're thinking of is called [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array). Although it'll work, it'll be a bit harder to maintain and more prone to bugs—IMO, at least.  Something object oriented would suit your needs much better.  So, what I'd do is create a model object and create and array of those objects to store the data.

```
struct MyModel {
    let event: String
    let review: String
    let date: NSDate
}
```

Then, assuming you have a cell that looks something like this:

```
class MyTableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var reviewTextView: UITextView!
}
```

Structure your data as an array of those models in your table view controller.  When the time comes to populate your cells, use the `indexPath` parameter in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` method to select the model from your models array.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var models = [MyModel]()

    lazy var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( "myIdentifier" ) as? MyTableCell {
            let model = self.models[ indexPath.row ]

            cell.eventLabel.text = model.event
            cell.dateLabel.text = self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(model.date)
            cell.reviewTextView.text = model.review

            return cell
        }
        fatalError( "Could not create cell" )
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.models.count
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the advice! Although it seems that this answer is suited for taking pre-existing data and building table cells. My question was about having empty textfields for a user to fill in and then extracting those values to be added to an array. Could you provide some guidance? Much appreciated!